# Connect sonar container to another postgres container exited after 8 seconds

Tags: postgresql, docker, sonarqube, dockerfile, docker-container

My Sonar-Dockerfile:

```
FROM sonarqube:lts-alpine
```

My sonar-startscript:

```
#!/bin/bash

image=sonarqube-test
container=test-sonar

docker stop ${container}
docker rm ${container}

docker rmi ${image}
docker build -t ${image} .

docker run -it -d --name ${container} \
        -p 9000:9000 -p 9092:9092 \
        -e SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=sonar \
        -e SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD=sonar \
        -e SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://x.x.x.x.x:5432/sonar \
        --add-host=database:x.x.x.x \
        ${image}
```

My Postgres-Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres:9.4

ENV POSTGRES_USER sonar
ENV POSTGRES_DB sonar

COPY pg_hba.conf      /tmp/pg_hba.conf
COPY updateConfig.sh  /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/_updateConfig.sh
```

My updateConfig.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

cat /tmp/pg_hba.conf > /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf
```

My pg_hba.conf:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             x.x.x.x/16              md5
host    all             all             127.17.0.0/16           md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     md5
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5

host all all all md5
```

My postgres startscript:

```
#!/bin/bash

image=psql.sql
container=test-psql

docker stop ${container}
docker rm ${container}

docker rmi ${image}
docker build -t ${image} .

docker run --name ${container} -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=sonar -d ${image}:latest
```

docker ps -a return:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS                    NAMES
234be4617f30        sonarqube-emo       "./bin/run.sh"           8 minutes ago       Exited (0) 8 minutes ago                            test-sonar
b76041559956        psql.sql:latest     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   11 minutes ago      Up 11 minutes              0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   test-psql
```

Logs of sonar-container:

```
2019.11.29 08:14:51 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.LogServerVersion] SonarQube Server / 6.7.5.38563 / ec8ab77fa180a9edaf664075e8e76ae0b4a2d9f1
2019.11.29 08:14:51 INFO  web[][o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:postgresql://x.x.x.x:5432/sonar
2019.11.29 08:14:52 WARN  web[][unknown.jul.logger] IOException occurred while connecting to x.x.x.x:5432
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Host is unreachable (Host unreachable)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:69)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:158)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:452)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:254)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
        at org.sonar.db.profiling.NullConnectionInterceptor.getConnection(NullConnectionInterceptor.java:31)
        at org.sonar.db.profiling.ProfiledDataSource.getConnection(ProfiledDataSource.java:323)
        at org.sonar.db.DefaultDatabase.checkConnection(DefaultDatabase.java:106)
        at org.sonar.db.DefaultDatabase.start(DefaultDatabase.java:75)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
        at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1016)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1009)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:767)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:134)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevel.start(PlatformLevel.java:90)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.start(Platform.java:211)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startLevel1Container(Platform.java:170)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.init(Platform.java:86)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.web.PlatformServletContextListener.contextInitialized(PlatformServletContextListener.java:45)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4745)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019.11.29 08:14:52 ERROR web[][o.postgresql.Driver] Connection error:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:259)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:452)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:254)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
        at org.sonar.db.profiling.NullConnectionInterceptor.getConnection(NullConnectionInterceptor.java:31)
        at org.sonar.db.profiling.ProfiledDataSource.getConnection(ProfiledDataSource.java:323)
        at org.sonar.db.DefaultDatabase.checkConnection(DefaultDatabase.java:106)
        at org.sonar.db.DefaultDatabase.start(DefaultDatabase.java:75)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
        at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1016)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1009)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:767)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:134)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevel.start(PlatformLevel.java:90)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.start(Platform.java:211)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startLevel1Container(Platform.java:170)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.init(Platform.java:86)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.web.PlatformServletContextListener.contextInitialized(PlatformServletContextListener.java:45)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4745)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Host is unreachable (Host unreachable)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:69)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:158)
        ... 42 common frames omitted
2019.11.29 08:14:52 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.Platform] Web server startup failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not connect to database. Please check connectivity and settings (see the properties prefixed by 'sonar.jdbc.').
        at org.sonar.db.DefaultDatabase.checkConnection(DefaultDatabase.java:108)
        at org.sonar.db.DefaultDatabase.start(DefaultDatabase.java:75)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
        at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1016)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1009)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:767)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:134)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevel.start(PlatformLevel.java:90)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.start(Platform.java:211)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startLevel1Container(Platform.java:170)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.init(Platform.java:86)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.web.PlatformServletContextListener.contextInitialized(PlatformServletContextListener.java:45)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4745)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The connection attempt failed.)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
        at org.sonar.db.profiling.NullConnectionInterceptor.getConnection(NullConnectionInterceptor.java:31)
        at org.sonar.db.profiling.ProfiledDataSource.getConnection(ProfiledDataSource.java:323)
        at org.sonar.db.DefaultDatabase.checkConnection(DefaultDatabase.java:106)
        ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:259)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:452)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:254)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
        ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Host is unreachable (Host unreachable)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:69)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:158)
        ... 42 common frames omitted
2019.11.29 08:14:52 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [web] is stopped
2019.11.29 08:14:52 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped
2019.11.29 08:14:52 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
2019.11.29 08:14:52 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractProcessMonitor] Process exited with exit value [es]: 143
```

x.x.x.x is the host-ipAddress. The Sonar-and postgresql-container are on the same host.

How can i connect sonarqube with a postgres-DB within another docker-container.

Comment: please add docker logs for the container

Comment: try to use the service name `test-psql` instead of the IP address

Comment: i got this expection java.net.UnknownHostException: test-psql

Comment: i didn't created it within docker compose

Comment: that is what I mean , use the same network when creating the docker containers , with --network mynetwork . then you can use the service name in your connection string

Comment: i created a network testnet and i started a postgres container with --network testnet. I changed the url in sonar to testnet:5432/sonar. I got java.net.UnknownHostException: testnet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203308/discussion-between-emoleumassi-and-linpy).

Answer (score 1):

I solved it:

for postgres, i created a network and i run my container within a network

```
docker network create testnet

docker run --name ${container} \
       -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=sonar \ 
       -d --network testnet ${image}:latest
```

for sonar, i run the container within the created network and i used the name of postgres's container in url:

```
docker run -it -d --name ${container} \
        -p 9000:9000 -p 9092:9092 \
        -e SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=sonar \
        -e SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD=sonar \
        -e SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://test-psql:5432/sonar \
        --net testnet \
        ${image}
```

If you work with sonar from 7.0, you have to increase the vm.max_map_count of you host.

```
sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=350000
```